# Adding a timestamp into mySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new into LAMP environment and wanted to add the timestamp into the mysql table every-time any user logs into the system but I am having some typo issues. Part of my index.php file is below. Thanks!

```
    if ($uname != "" && $password != ""){

        $sql_query = "select count(*) as cntUser from users where username='".$uname."' and password='".$password."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        $count = $row['cntUser'];

        if($count > 0)
        {
        $_SESSION['uname'] = $uname;

**$timestamper = "UPDATE 'users' SET timestamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() WHERE username='".$uname."'";
mysql_query($timestamper);
header('Location: home.php');**

        }
        else
        {
            echo "Invalid username and password";
        }

    }
```

My table looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qMyX.jpg

Comment: you are using `mysql_query()` instead of `mysqli_query($con, $timestamper)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you should have to alter your database schema also.
Let me explain you,

First add below columns to your db

1. `is_login` (datatype (enum) with values 0/1 )
2. `last_login_datetime` (datatype (timestamp), attibutes (on update current timestamp), default (current timestamp) )

Now when user logs in the system, set `is_login` flag to one and at the same time system will automatically update your `last_login_datetime`,
with the help of this, if future you can also use this `is_login` field in many terms and this will help you alot.